# How can I test for [AllowHtml] attribute within an editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, mvc-editor-templates

I would like to be able to test a property for the [AllowHtml] attribute from within an editor template.

It doesn't seem to be lurking within `ViewData.ModelMetadata`.

I've tried iterating through `ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues` to see if it's there, but it doesn't appear to be.

I've scoured Google and [Brad Wilson's post on templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html), but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to do some heavy lifting in the template like:

```
var allowHtmlAttribute = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata
  .ContainerType
  .GetProperty(this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowHtmlAttribute), false)
  .Select(a => a as AllowHtmlAttribute)
  .FirstOrDefault(a => a != null);
```

and now that I think about it, a Extension Method would be great!

```
public static class ModelMetadataExtensions
{
  public T GetPropertyAttribute<T>(this ModelMetadata instance)
    where T : Attribute
  {
    var result = instance.ContainerType
      .GetProperty(instance.PropertyName)
      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
      .Select(a => a as T)
      .FirstOrDefault(a => a != null);

    return result;
  } 
}
```

Then

```
var myAttribute = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata
  .GetPropertyAttribute<AllowHtmlAttribute>();
```

Comment: It was your last answer that got me delving into this in the first place! Thanks for 2 brilliant answers in one day. :)

Comment: I implemented the extension. The `Select(a => a as T) ` line gave me an error.  *The type parameter T cannot be used with the as operator because it does not have a class type constraint*.   I added `where T : Attribute` to the definition which made the error go away, but  that was a total guess and there may be a better way to solve it.